# Visual Studio Code Webview Provider

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview, vscode-extensions, vscode-webview

*Clarity on what a webview provider is and how to create one.*

I'm currently working on creating an extension within VSCode. *Just to add, i'm very new to software developing so my terminology may be a bit incorrect.*

I realized creating a webview view (So a webview that's displayed within a 'view' i.e. the sections within a view container) is a lot different than creating a basic webview panel. It requires you to have a 'webview provider' which is not explained very well in their documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WebviewView

Are there any resources someone can provide to help bring some clarity on what a Webview Provider is and creating one?